# Linear program with none empty feasible set and bounded objective

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

It is clear to see that if the feasible region of a linear programming problem is nonempty and bounded, then the objective function attains both a maximum and minimum value and these occur at extreme points of the feasible region.

What if the feasible region of a linear programming problem is nonempty (do not know about boundedness) and **the objective function is bounded** in the feasible set? Can we conclude that the linear program has a finite optimal solution?

This intuitively seems true, but how do I go about proving it?

Comment: Cant you just solve the LP problem like normal?  If the objective function achieves a value outside of its bounds then simply limit it to the bound.

Comment: If the objective function is bounded then it can be written as a non-strict inequality... and this can be written as one of your basic equations, $Ax \le b$.